# Test condition with function call and simple test performing about the same

Tags: c

I'm doing a benchmark with two versions of a function to filter a linked list, one that receives a predicate function as an argument, and one in which the predicate is built into the function using a "macro template". I would expect the first to run more slowly, because it is making a function call on every iteration, but on my box their speeds are about the same. Any clue about why is this happening? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

struct list_t {
    int val;
    struct list_t *next;
};
typedef struct list_t list_t;

// Removes elements not matching the predicate.
// NOTE: This is not freeing the removed elements.

list_t *keep(int (*predfun)(int,int), int predarg, list_t *list) {
    list_t *this, *prev;

    for (this=list, prev=NULL; this; prev=this, this=this->next) {
        if (!predfun(this->val, predarg)) {
            if (!prev) {
                list = this->next;
            }
            else {
                prev->next = this->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}

int less(int a, int b) {
    return a<b;
}

// A "template" macro for the keep function.
// The idea is to embed the predicate into the function, so that we
// don't have to make a function call on each iteration.

#define build_keep(test) {                                           \
    list_t *this, *prev;                                             \
                                                                     \
    for (this=list, prev=NULL; this; prev=this, this=this->next) {   \
        if (!(test)) {                                               \
            if (!prev) {                                             \
                list = this->next;                                   \
            }                                                        \
            else {                                                   \
                prev->next = this->next;                             \
            }                                                        \
        }                                                            \
    }                                                                \
    return list;                                                     \
}


list_t *keep_less(int arg, list_t *list) {
    build_keep(this->val < arg);
}

#define LEN 1000000
#define MOD 1024

// Creates a new list.
list_t *buildlist() {
    int i;
    list_t *list, *last, *t;
    list=NULL, last=NULL;
    srand(0); // Using always the same seed for the benchmark.
    for (i=0; i<LEN; i++) {
        if (!last) {
            last = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
            list = last;
        }
        else {
            last->next = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
            last = last->next;
        }
        last->val = rand() % MOD;
    }
    last->next = NULL;
    return list;
}    

int main() {
    struct timeval t0, t1;
    list_t *list, *t;

    // With macro.
    list = buildlist();
    //for (t=list; t; t=t->next) printf("%d ", t->val); printf("\n");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    keep_less(500, list);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("keep_less: %lf\n", (1000000 * (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + (t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec))/1000000.0);
    //for (t=list; t; t=t->next) printf("%d ", t->val); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");

    // Without macro.
    list = buildlist();
    //for (t=list; t; t=t->next) printf("%d ", t->val); printf("\n");
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    keep(less, 500, list);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    printf("keep: %lf\n", (1000000 * (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + (t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec))/1000000.0);
    //for (t=list; t; t=t->next) printf("%d ", t->val); printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output here is:

```
keep_less: 0.181019

keep: 0.185590
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say the results are about the same - you do see a 4 milisecond (~2%) difference in favor of the immediate version.

This is actually relatively substantial - it's possible to achieve such a high saving with saving just a function call only because your test functions did very little to start with. If you expected more out of this optimization, you might have stumbled upon an [important lesson](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)... (that personally, I have to re-learn once every few weeks :] )

Comment: Right. I benchmarked a for with 1000000 function calls vs. 1000000 additions and the difference is about the same (6ms). So, I think I've learned it (at least for now). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Ofek didn't really answer the question ;-) which is *why is that happening?*. Obviously the compiler is doing a pretty good job, here.

- Function calls by themselves are not
  as costly as many people think, even
  if going through a function pointer.
  This is specially true when done in a
  loop, where the function then is in
  the instruction cache after the first
  iteration.
- If all function code is present in
  one compilation unit any good
  compiler nowadays will be able to
  `inline` small functions (like
  `less`) into the caller.
- In the extreme, by constant
  propagation, it might even get away
  with no dynamic calling at all. After
  all `less` is constant, here, in the place `keep` is called.

Without doing over-optimization to have similar effects on code that is not present in the same unit I tend to use `inline` quite systematically. This doesn't guarantee at all that a function will be inlined, but simply permits to have the definition of the function body in a header file.